# Swift UIView with multiply effect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, swift2

What I've been trying to achieve for a couple of hours is something like the following:
[image]

I would like to have a `UIImage` in the background and then preferably a `UIView` with a background color of red with some kind of multiply effect (the red area). Is this possible? I've seen a few extensions for UIImage that tints them, but that would only work if I wanted my WHOLE image to have a red multiply color effect.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried something yet? Just for clarification: The image is the background of some view and you want another view on top of that view, and everywhere the new view is you want the background to be rendered red-ish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just add a red `UIView` to the top of your `UIImageView`. Adjust the alpha to make it transparent:

```
let someView = UIView(frame: someImageView.frame)
someView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255.0/255.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
someImageView.addSubview(someView)
```

Using a multiply instead:

```
let img = UIImage(named: “background”)
let img2 = UIImage(named: “effect”) //Make sure this is your red image same size as the background


let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, true, 0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

// fill the background with white so that translucent colors get lighter
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

img.drawInRect(rect, blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1)
img2.drawInRect(rect, blendMode: .Multiply, alpha: 1)

// grab the finished image and return it
let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: for example: http://i.imgur.com/9RsBSPh.jpg - the red is unfortunately not as vibrant.

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. I want a MULTIPLY effect. You're just adjusting the alpha channel, that's why it's not as vibrant.

Comment: @GustafGunér try the multiply filter in CoreGraphics. Adjust the alpha as needed. See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3** Extension (thx to @Kex):

```
extension UIImage{
    class func multiply(image:UIImage, color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)

        //image colored
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //image multiply
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // fill the background with white so that translucent colors get lighter
        context!.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        image.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
        coloredImage?.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .multiply, alpha: 1)

        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let image = UIImage.multiply(image: sourceImage, color: UIColor.red)
```

Comment: For copy & paste users: UIColor(hex: Constants.RED_COLOR) is not an API call and Constants.RED_COLOR too.

Answer (score 5):

With **iOS10** you can now use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to add a partial multiply effect as easy as this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func tinted(_ color: UIColor, percentageFromBottom: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let imageRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        let colorRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: (1.0 - percentageFromBottom) * size.height, width: size.width, height: percentageFromBottom * size.height)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)

        let tintedImage = renderer.image { context in
            color.set()
            context.fill(colorRect)
            draw(in: imageRect, blendMode: .multiply, alpha: 1)
        }

        return tintedImage
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this to multiply the lower third of the original with a red multiply:

```
UIImage(named: "trees")?.tinted(.red, percentageFromBottom: 0.33)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Comment: In the extension, "size" is not defined.

Comment: ˋsizeˋ is a property of ˋUIImageˋ and the extension is of ˋUIImage´

Comment: Can we get the image tinted exclude the transparent area using your code? I've tried but the whole image got tinted including the transparent area.

Comment: @Heobien You could try to create a maskView with the image and apply it to the UIImageView to dislpays the image. That should work.

Comment: @joern Yeah, I've manipulated a bit with draw function and found that just add 1 more draw "draw(in: imageRect, blendMode: .destinationIn, alpha: 1)" before the "multiply" could solve my problem. Thanks for your recommendation though.

Comment: @Heobien Awesome, thanks for sharing your solution!