# How to set alpha of a UIView and don't lose the sharpness and colour quality

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I want to set alpha of a `UIView` in such a way that don't lose the sharpness and colour quality of the view and don't make it dull. I set the Alpha of a view that have background image, from storyboard but my view's colour got dull. I want to maintain the sharpness of the view's color.

This is what I got, (img-1)

[image]

This is what I want, (img-2)

[image]

You can observe that there is some sharpness and darkness in img-2, that is what I want.

Comment: Please add image of your UI.

Comment: I have tried to upload but could not found any option so I uploaded in google drive and shared the link. Please have a look and guide.

Comment: you can see that there is dullness in img-1, I played with multiple values but could not got the img-2 result.

Comment: give me your red color code (RGB pr hex) so i will try .

Comment: what is your requirement ? Do u want transparent view or what ?

Comment: It is not an alpha layer.  It is using a multiply blend mode.  A solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483352/swift-uiview-with-multiply-effect

Comment: Setting the alpha to anything less than 1 will inevitably "mix" the background's color with the view's color. In this case, your background is white so your view becomes a little whiter. That's what it means to be semi-transparent. What you want is quite contradictory.

Comment: thankyou all espacially Job Rose. Let me try your provided example.

Comment: Job, I don't want to create filter for image. Actually it is UICollectionView in front of ImageView. I need to set Alpha or something so that image could be little visible.